# Установка PyQt5

Tags: pyqt5, python-3.5

[image: ![][1]]
[image: ![][2]]

Не могу запустить скрипты с использованием PyQt5. Пытался ставить через консоль версию 5.11.2 и собранную 5.6. Сейчас стоит как раз 5.6, поэтому ее нет в списке. Вообщем и так, и так выползает одна и та же ошибка. Сам PyQt5 импортируется, функция `help()` выдает по нему инфу, но по всем подклассам ошибка и все.

Comment: `pip3 install PyQt5`?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше приводить в виде текста.

Comment: @gil9red да, я так тоже пытался, не работает.

Comment: @Антон, что пишет?

Comment: @gil9red то что в приложенных скринах. Говорю же, он устанавливается, но почему то импортировать подклассы не получается. Вроде еще что-то было про DLL, но это если пытаться использовать методы этих подклассов, которые он не находит. Кстати я где то читал, что при проблемах надо куда-то какие-то DLL закинуть, правда вот комментатор не уточнял какие и куда.

Comment: До установки PyQt5 не стояла например PyQ4 или PySide?

Comment: Проблема может быть из-за кириллицы в имени пользователя...